# Residue class ring problem

Tags: linear-algebra

We look for a prime p for the residue class ring $(\mathcal{R_p},\oplus,\circ)$
(note the circle at the end means multiplication in $\mathcal{R_p}$ but I do not know how to write it).

a) Let $y\in\mathcal{R_p}\setminus{0}$ and $x,x'\in\mathcal{R_p}$

Prove that if $x\neq{x'}$ it follows that $y\circ{x}\neq{y\circ{x'}}$

b) Conclude that $(\mathcal{R_n},\oplus,\circ)$ is only a field when n is prime

Comment: What is $\mathcal R$?

Comment: its a ring modulo p in this case

Comment: And what is a ‘ring modulo $p$’?

Comment: its just a ring and the elements are of the form $[a]_p$

Comment: But what does $p$ denote in this context?

Comment: a prime number, so it would be modulo p

Comment: So I guess $\mathcal R$ is but $\mathbf Z$, isn't it?

Comment: Its in the reals, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. As far as I understand you have to prove that $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$ is a field *if and  only only if* $n$ is a prime.

If $np$ is prime, you're asked to prove that multiplication by any $y\neq0$ is injective. This will result from *Euclid's lemma* (if a prime divides a product, it divides one of the factors).

Furthermore, as $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$ is finite, we know that injective implies bijective. Thus $1$ is attained, i. e. there exists a $z$ such that $zy\equiv 1\mod p$. In other words , if $y\neq 0$, it has an inverse modulo $p$, which is the definition of a field.